# How do I force ListView to garbage collect all of its views? (When having more than 1 ListView with a ViewPager)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have image intensive listviews that I need to GC, normally it would be fine with just a single listview in a single activity, however I have a ViewPager with 3 screens that all have image intensive ListViews. I have the event on swipe to next screen, but how can I force the ListViews that are not active (in view) to recycle its views? Thanks.

Comment: as long as you are not viewing the page that has the list view and that the view pager is 2 pages away it's not even cached, but the views will not be recycled if you didn't use `convertView` in your adapter logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about that. ListView is carefully designed to take care of views (listItems) inside and not to spend extra memory while scrolling. It actually recycles the views. However, regarding *GC*, when you destroy your activity by calling **finish()**, the framework automatically handles the resources and releases them.